# How to call this operation [shown on a image]?

Tags: algorithms

How do you call thing like that?

[image]

**EDIT:** at first there is 1135, we sum every siblings: 1+1, 1+3, 3+5 - results are 2, 4 and 8. Sum again: 2+4, 4+8: results - 6 and 12; 6 is digit so ok but 12 is greater than 9 so we sum 1 and 2 to get 3. Next, 6 + 3= 9 and 9 is eventual digit here.

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm? Why is there no 'v' shape between the middle and the fourth row?

Comment: Till we get a single digit, we reduce a big number by suming 1st word with 2nd, 2nd with 3rd, 3rd with 4th etc, I mean: for a number **X** consisting of **n** digits, the eventual result is (X[1]+X[2])+(X[2]+X[3]+...+(X[n-1]+X[n]).

Comment: But this is something different than shown in your graphics! (And still, can you explain the thrid step in your image?)

Comment: Third step - I want to have only digits and there are 6 and 12, so digits in 12 (1 and 2) is being summed to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where $F(r,c) =$ the $r^{th}$ row, $c^{th}$ column entry (and ignoring the existence of the third row which should never have been drawn [6, 12]), it appears that you have defined the function as:  $$F(r+1,c) = F(r,c) + F(r,c+1)\!\! \mod 9$$ where $1\leq r$, $1\leq c$, and $r+c\leq 5$, and initial conditions $F(1,1)=1, F(1,2)=1, F(1,3)=3, F(1,4)=5$

I say you should not have drawn the third row for the reason that, although it works alright for a computer, it is very clumsy in math that way.  We would prefer to run a single loop is possible, and not have a second loop that activates only under certain conditions inside.  The $\mod 9$ has the same desired effect of forcing all entries to be $0\leq F(r,c)\leq 9$, and will retain the same value of the result of summing the digits of a 2 digit number.

[image]

Consider a different set of initial conditions: $6,2,5,8$.  On the left I show my modified version, and on the right I show your original algorithm for comparison.

[image]

Notice again how the modified version remains a triangle.

What would I call this scenario?  **A multi-dimensional recurrence relation**. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)
.  The specific output might be best obtained by running through the function itself, and can be seen to be *related* to the original number (the concatenation of the initial conditions) mod 9, however the exact result gets thrown off by the number and location of times one has to change the number due to the modding process during the algorithm.

Consider the final example with a permutation of the initial conditions:

[image]